# Installing Linux on my Android Device

Tags: linux, android, steam

Is there a way where I can install Linux on this device to steam games using the STEAM client without a PC and any problems?

---

I am currently without a PC and am thinking of alternative ways, i.e. possibly through the use of Linux, that i could use my android device to run PC games by mainly streaming them through Steam. Below is some information on my device specs and latest benchmark test results to show that it does in fact have the "umph" to run games through Steam no problem. I guess my main question is this, Is there any way that i can stream games from my android phone device, through the Steam CLient, without a PC?

**DEVICE INFORMATION**
CPUZ April 22, 2023 Benchmark:
https://valid.x86.fr/a/w4aqpm

| **DEVICE** | Samsung Galaxy s21+ 5g 128Gb |
| --- | --- |
| **Manufacturer** | Samsung |
| **Model ID** | SM-G996U |
| **Android Version** | 13 |
| **Kernel Version** | 5.4.210-qgki-25911719-abG996USQS6EWCA |
| **Battery Capacity** | 4660 mAh |

| **SoC (Processor)** | amd64-v8 (aarch64) |
| --- | --- |
| Architecture | arm64-v8 (aarch64) |
| SoC Model | ARM Cortex-A55+ARM Cortex-A78+ARM Cortex-X1 |
| SoC Family | 4x ARM Cortex-A55 @1.80 GHz+3x ARM Cortex-A78 @2.42 GHz+1x ARM Cortex-X1 @2.84 G |
| Frequency | 998 MHz / Min: 300 MHz - Max: 2841 MHz |
| Main CPU Cores | 8 Cores / 8 Threads |
| Features | FP ASIMD EVTSTRM AES PMULL SHA1 SHA2 CRC32 ATOMICS FPHP ASIMDHP CPUID ASIMDRDM LRCPC DCPOP ASIMDDP |
| Bogomips | 38.40 MIPS |

| **Display (GPU / LCD)** |  |
| --- | --- |
| SoC Manufacturer | Qualcomm |
| SoC Model | Adreno (TM) 660 |
| OpenGL | Ver. 3.2 |
| LCD Size | 13.8 inches / 35.1 cm |
| LCD Resolution | 1920 x 1080 pixels |
| LCD Definition | 160 DPI |

| **Memory** |  |
| --- | --- |
| RAM | 7361 MB (8 GB) |
| Flash | 107408 MB |

Comment: Most games don't have ARM releases, so you'd need to use an x86 emulator and even if your phone had enough power to run these games, I don't think it would that well with emulation required.

Comment: Technically, your phone is already running Linux, specifically kernel version 5.4.210

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way where I can install Linux on this device to steam games *without any problems*?

Definitely not. While Android in fact already runs a Linux kernel, getting a typical desktop Linux ported to a phone is a very nontrivial task, especially because you need to get all the vendor drivers for sounds and graphics hardware, power control and wireless to work on something that is not the vendor-modified Android environment.

That is a lot of work and takes an embedded engineer with specific experience, or a lot of time to learn by themselves. It also needs you to have access to a PC on which you can build a lot of software, attach a device to your phone, flash your phone etc. 
You could still fail at any point, when somthing in vendor drivers is just too broken to be ported to be interoperable with your user land (e.g. writing a graphics driver for X11 or Wayland against a vendor KMS driver is no fun).

If you're able to do that, I'm pretty optimistic you could find a freelancing client that would pay you to get Linux up and running on their devices and earn the money needed to buy a steam deck in significantly shorter time, with less probability of failure.

Answer (score 0):

With *your* device what @MarcusMüller wrote in his answer perhaps applies. There are devices, though, which are explicitly designed for a dual-boot usage, for instance the [Volla phone](https://volla.online/en/index.html). Notice, though, that it uses AOSP, a de-googled Android without Google Apps and Play Services. This is good for your privacy, but perhaps bad for your gaming experience.

You *could* use [microG](https://microg.org/) and try your hand at the [Aurora](https://aurora-store.en.uptodown.com/android) or [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/) app stores, but your mileage may vary if you are used to using Google services. There is also the possibility to anonymously use the Google store.

For the Linux side of the dual-boot system there is [Ubuntu Touch](https://ubuntu-touch.io/). It works with many (rooted) phones but notice that you need a PC to install it. In short: you install the packages *adb*, *fastboot* and *ubports-installer*, then connect your phone via USB to the PC and start *ubports-installer*.

PS: I said above that the Volla phone is dual boot. The web site says so, the developers say so and a German computer magazine (LinuxUser 04/23, p78ff) said so in an article about the Volla phone 22 and X23, but obviously @ChanganAuto (see his comment below) knows better and they are all a bunch of liars.

The mentioned article also claims that

> Möchten Sie Android lieber meiden, steht Ihnen mit Ubutuntu Touch eine Linux-Variante zur Verfügung, die das Volla Phone 22 ebenfalls zum mittlerweile tauglichen Begleiter durch Ihren Tag macht.
> <sub>If you want to avoid Android, there is Ubuntu Touch, a Linux-variant which makes the Volla Phone 22 a capable companion for your day.</sub>